# Pros/Cons to disabling HEAD requests with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, security, http, http-headers, headers

I have a static blog/site and I'm wondering if there are any negative implications of disallowing/disabling HEAD requests within my Nginx conf? For example: would it break the site with certain web browser? Are their any security implications with disabling HEAD requests?

Comment: You will get a lot of opionions on this.  For a blog, you should be fine to disable everything except `GET` and `POST` (for your comment section)

Comment: Your blog will also work fine if you disable pictures. And it will be really fast if it has no content. But both of those would be just stupid - kind of like disabling HEAD requests for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real benefit to disallowing HEAD requests. Clients can use this to check if their cache is up to date. Disabling it will most likely cause them to retry with a GET.  HEAD is used often enough though that I'm curious why you want to block it.

Comment: I have DDoS attacks with HEAD requests